# Почему при передаче в QML значение типа String выскакивает ошибка?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

> ReferenceError: str is not defined

как  это пременную можно определить, хотя значения типа int приходит.

QML

```
Connections {

    target: backend 


    onSetToQml: {


        console.log("QML " + str  );

    }

}
```

В самом слое содержимое пременной С++ выводится.

Heder

```
signal

 void setToQml(Qstring str);
```

Cpp

```
MyMetod{

QString str= "tor"

emit setToQml(str);
}
```

Так же я передаю int и с ним вопросов не возникает.

Comment: Приведите код на C++, который посылает сигнал, который вы ловите. QString должен нормально обрабатываться

Comment: Ну то есть у вас там должен быть сигнал по типу `void setToQml(const QString& str)`, чтобы то что вы написали в QML работало.

Comment: @vegorov добавил код, да всё это есть. А обязательно const и & ссылку ставить в хедере?

Comment: даже не знаю тогда, вряд ли передача по константной ссылке что-то изменит.

Comment: у Вас же emit где-то в методе происходит, после конструктора ? а не так как в примере ?

Comment: @vegorov да в методе

Comment: может опечатались где.

Comment: @vegorov врядли int же проходит, вот если вам нужно было передать текст qml как вы бы это сделали ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78601/discussion-between-vegorov-and-varg-sieg).